# Decide which network will be correct

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a dataset that requires 20 inputs and 20 outputs. To increase accuracy, the output was reduced to 1, and 20 individual networks, which are trained off the same input to the appropriate target output. Each network is training to a validation error of 0.01 RMS or better. However when I go to check it with a separate "real world" dataset the performance of each seperate network acts in an unpredictable way. I really only need 7-10 of the outputs, but due to the variability I'm working with all 20. Is there a way to track which will output the most accurate output each time or better way to have a 20 in 10 out network? The main issue is my application requires an integer, hence the absolute accuracy issue due to rounding. I am using a sigmoid hidden layer, with my dataset normalized between 0 and 1. The network is done using Neupy for Python.

Comment: I get the feeling you seem to be trying to optimize a "garbage in, garbage out" problem.

Comment: @tripleee Are there any test to verify this? I was beginning to think the same or I was doing something wrong.

Comment: More real-world testing? If as you say the behavior is erratic, that would usually be a symptom of inadequate training (meaning either of not enough of it, or a problem where your method basically doesn't work).

Comment: @tripleee      Do you have any suggestions for improving training that I can try?

Comment: Uh, without access to your data it's pretty much impossible to predict what will work. If the data is basically noise, no amount of training will find useful patterns, with any method.